# How to detect query from Room in Flow returns no values and insert new record so that its reflected in the Flow

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, kotlin-flow

I need to be able to have my ViewModel handle situation when query returning some data from Room database (in a StateFlow) is null (returns 0 records) and insert new field then ensure it is reflected in the StateFlow for the UI to display the updated value.

I tried to implement it in the initialValue initialization of the .stateIn function but it turns out initialValue is always called before the actual query starts flowing in the Flow and results in duplicate entry trying to be inserted into the database.

How should I accomplish it in the most optimal and proper way?

My relevant code is below:

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
data class Setting (
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    val name: String,
    val valueInt: Int?,
    val valueString: String?
)
```

**Dao:**

```
@Dao
interface SettingDao{
    @Query ("SELECT * FROM Setting WHERE name = :name")
    fun getSettingsByName(name : String): Flow<List<Setting>>

    @Query ("INSERT INTO Setting VALUES(:key, :valueInt, :valueString)")
    suspend fun addSetting(key: String, valueInt: Int?, valueString: String?)
}
```

**Repository:**

```
class SettingsRepository(
    private val settingDao: SettingDao) {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    fun getSettingsStream(key: String): Flow<Setting> = 
        settingDao.getSettingsByName(key).flatMapConcat { it.asFlow() }

    suspend fun addSetting(key: String, valueInt: Int?, valueString: String) = 
        settingDao.addSetting(key, valueInt, valueString)
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
Class SettingsViewModel(
    private val settingsRepository: SettingsRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val settingsState : StateFlow<SettingsState> =
        combine(
            settingsRepository.getSettingsStream("appId")
        ) {
            appId ->
            SettingsState(
                appId
                    .filterNotNull()
                    .first()
                    .valueString
            )
        }
        .stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
            SettingsState(generateAppId())
    )
    
    private fun generateAppId() : String {
        val newId = "app" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().takeLast(12)
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
           settingsRepository.addSetting("appId", null, newId)
        }
        return newId
    }
}

data class SettingsState(
    val appId: String? = "not_loaded"
)
```